# How to avoid multiple bitmap instantiation in list view, when fetching asynchronously?

Tags: android, listview

**Problem**

I have a problem with bitmaps and the listview's behaviour of calling getView() on each position multiple times.

My list contains only bitmaps and fetches them asynchronously from a remote location. Now, when the listview is displayed, since getView() is called about 4 times for each position (without scrolling), it will instantiate 4 different bitmap instances for the same position (and use only one...), and this causes out of memory error.

**What I tried**

I have already a bitmap cache, but this happens before having fetched the images the very first time. E.g. listView is opened, makes 4 requests for the bitmap for position 0, once this arrives, saves the bitmap in the cache. After this, the problem is solved. But my problem is about the first time creating 4 bitmaps (for item 0, item 1, item 2, item 3 -> 16 bitmaps, and I just needed 4).

I already tried out some strategies to solve this, like implementing a list of "waiting" imageViews, and fetch only for one, and then set the bitmap for all the waiting ones, but this generated new problems and it's also difficult to synchronize.

I tried also adding a list-field with already fetched positions of the listview, in order to fetch and set only once, getView() seems to generate a different image view (or the like) each time (I'm recycling convertView, but anyways), since I end with empty positions (although all the bitmaps where fetched, instantiated and set in one of the imageviews).
To solve this I used a map-field which maps position to List of ImageView, and set the bitmap to all the imageViews which where called for one position. Should work, but it also doesn't. In most positions I get the correct bitmaps, but, for example, in the first position of the list, I get the bitmap from the last visible position (I can see it switches fast, first it shows bitmap from position 0, then 1, then 2, and then 3 -my last visible position-). This is solved if I turn off recycling (inflate convertView each time), but this is of course not a good solution.

Another possibility which comes to my mind, but feels like a terrible solution (like the other ones), is to pre-fetch the bitmaps, so, before the list scrolls, I have already next x bitmaps in the cache.  This would be implemented in combination with a scrolllistener, where scrolling causes to fetch the next x items and put them in the cache. So when the list calls getView() (no matter how offen), it will always get the same prefetched bitmap instance from the cache).

I should not be the only one with this problem, since list / grid views with bitmaps fetched from the web are very common...

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My strategy was to do 2 requests - the first to determine the original size of the image, the second to request an scaled down image (by a power of 2. 8 or 16 was ok for thumbnails). I found a lot of useful information in SO, as it's a common problem. Sorry I don't have code right now, that's why I'm not answering.

Comment: I'm already requesting a small image size. The issue is, this list is in a dialog, not a separate activity, and I have already loaded a lot of other things, so I have to care about every unnecessary loaded bit.

Comment: With small images I mean images which occupy ~409 kb memory on the device. This is not a lot if load only 1 for each item, but creating 16 (or sometimes more) is ~6mb at once, and if I have already 10 mb occupied with the other things, this will cause out of memory on some devices. I can't use lower size images because this is the final size (they are not linked or such), and they have to look good.

Comment: I seem to be posting this link a lot lately, but have you seen this? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html The code example shows an excellent use of loading web images and caching them. Everything you need to know is in there.

Comment: I don't think so. I have already a cache system, and I already read that. But this certain issue is not covered there.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this behaviour happens only for the first visible items. When I scroll down the list until the end, it still keeps calling `getView()` for the very first items, but for the rest, it calls just one time.

For the first list items it could make sense to pre-load the bitmaps, so they are already in memory when the list calls `getView()`, and will not be instantiated. For now I improved memory usage in other parts of my application, such that this problem doesn't crash the device.